# Can I use for in a constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a constructor like this, where I declare my route on Trimble Maps,

```
  var myRoute = new TrimbleMaps.Route({
        routeId: "myRoute",
        vehType: 0,
        routeType: 0,
        distUnits: 0,
        fuelUnits: 0,

        stops: [
          new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[0].Long, pointsArray[0].Lat),
          new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[1].Long, pointsArray[1].Lat),
          new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[2].Long, pointsArray[2].Lat),
          new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[3].Long, pointsArray[3].Lat),
          new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[4].Long, pointsArray[4].Lat),
          new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[5].Long, pointsArray[5].Lat),
          // new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[6].Long, pointsArray[6].Lat),
        ],
      });
```

but I want **stops** to look to look something like,
There is a way to do this ?

```
for(let i = 0 ; i <pointsArray.length ; i++){
 stops: [
          new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[i].Long, pointsArray[i].Lat),
       
        ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this:

```js
var myRoute = new TrimbleMaps.Route({
  ...
  stops: pointsArray.map((item, i) =>
    new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(pointsArray[i].Long, pointsArray[i].Lat));
  ),
  ...
});
```

Comment: but how can i  do  stops array depends on points.array length , because if i have 6 elements on stops  and just 2,3 on pointsArray it will be undefined

Comment: Instead of index `i`, you can also use `item` which denotes the current element. Like `new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(item.Long, item.Lat));`